# TensorBoard error : path /[[_dataImageSrc]] not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was trying to run TensorBoard example : mnist_with_summaries.py and when I tried to open an instance of TensorBoard I got this :

command:
'tensorboard --logdir=/output --host localhost --port=6006'

output:
'TensorBoard 1.5.1 at http://localhost:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
W0219 15:12:02.944875 Thread-1 application.py:273] path /[[_dataImageSrc]] not found, sending 404'

When I try to open http://localhost:6006, my browser crash.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, with tensorflow GPU and the 1.5.1 version

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this:

DO NOT USE "" or '' in the logdir path. Say, if you cd into the parent folder of log files (training folder is my log files parent folder), use "tensorboard --logdir=training" instead of "tensorboard --logdir='training'". This method works for my environment.

Comment: I found that my Mozilla Firefox wasn't up to date, after updating it the problem was fixed. But thank you !

Answer (score -1):

This is because you entered the wrong directory. For example, the file is in `E:/path/to/log/events.out.tfevents.1526472789.DESKTOP-CUF1KNI`

you should `cd` to the `E:/path/to/"directory,ues "tensorboard --logdir=log`

You may `cd` the `E:/path/to/log` directory, this will cause the error.